# Parsing GraphQL schema fails unexpectedly

Tags: antlr4

As part of our Clojure GraphQL library, we parse GraphQL schema definition using this grammar:

https://github.com/walmartlabs/lacinia/blob/master/resources/com/walmartlabs/lacinia/schema.g4

Something that slipped through the crack until recently (hello, eating our own dogfood) is that the following valid SDL fails to parse:

```
directive @auth (
              logFailure: Boolean = true
            ) on FIELD_DEFINITION
```

Here are the parse errors:

```
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Failed to parse GraphQL schema.
    errors: ({:locations [{:line 2, :column nil}],
              :message
              "mismatched input 'true' expecting {'{', '[', EXECUTABLE_DIRECTIVE_LOCATION, TYPE_SYSTEM_DIRECTIVE_LOCATION, 'type', 'implements', 'interface', 'schema', 'enum', 'union', 'input', 'directive', 'extend', 'scalar', 'on', 'fragment', 'query', 'mutation', 'subscription', 'value', BooleanValue, Name, NullValue, IntValue, FloatValue, StringValue, BlockStringValue}"}
             {:locations [{:line 3, :column nil}],
              :message "mismatched input ')' expecting ':'"})
```

So, despite the rules in the grammar to match `true` and `false` as BooleanValue, and `null` as NullValue, the parser is failing.

I've already done some thrashing ... reordering rules in the grammar to ensure that BooleanValue is checked before other things, but I continue to get the same error. I'm not sure how to identify the root problem here.

Anything obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the lexer will never produce a `BooleanValue` token:

```
K_TRUE         : 'true'         ;
K_FALSE        : 'false'        ;
...

BooleanValue
    : K_TRUE
    | K_FALSE
    ;
```

because `K_TRUE` and `K_FALSE` are defined before `BooleanValue`. This is how ANTLR's lexer works:

- match as much characters as possible for a lexer rule
- whenever there are 2 or more lexer rules that match the same characters, let the rule defined first "win"

The solution is to promote `BooleanValue` to the parser:

```
K_TRUE         : 'true'         ;
K_FALSE        : 'false'        ;
...

booleanValue
    : K_TRUE
    | K_FALSE
    ;

...

value
    : IntValue
    | FloatValue
    | StringValue
    | BlockStringValue
    | booleanValue
    | NullValue
    | enumValue
    | arrayValue
    | objectValue
    ;
```

and your input would be parsed correctly:

[image]

Btw, the same goes for `NullValue`: it will never be created as a token since `K_NULL` is defined before it. Easiest is just to remove it as a lexer rule and use `K_NULL` directly in your parser rules.

Comment: Thanks!  I had given this a try before but it didn't work, I must have done it wrong.  I'll give it a new try and loop back with the results.  Life saver!

Comment: No problemo @HowardM.LewisShip, let me know if this fixed it for you.

Comment: To confirm: yes, that change made all the difference.  Thanks again for your help!